# Any way to speed up this bit list code?

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation

I store a variable amount of bits in a list. I need to look up the bits in the range of [i,j]. Currently I'm storing the bits in a vector of unsigned 32 bit integers.

This is how I do the lookup:

```
std::uint32_t
Data::findInt3(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& input, int size, int pos) {
    pos = pos*size;
    int firstc = pos >> 5;
    int ipos = pos & 31;
    int end = ipos+size;
    std::uint64_t t = input[firstc];

    std::uint64_t num = (t << 32) | input[firstc+1];
    std::uint64_t number = num >> (64-end);
    number = number & ((1 << size)-1);

    return number;
}
```

This piece of code is called A LOT of times. I guess just small speed-ups will be very beneficial. Can anyone see anything which could be made better? Like shifting something instead of or'ing. Or which is faster?

Thanks

Comment: Don't guess, measure.

Comment: This doesn't look like a big bottleneck.

Comment: There's `_bextr_u64`, but that's not widely supported yet..

Answer (score 3):

That piece of code performs several things :

1. it calculates the index
2. it access a vector, using calculated index (I guess it is some kind of lookup table)
3. it calculates a result using the vector's value

So, by just looking at it, it doesn't look like it can be optimised without showing how it is used, and without the knowledge of the whole algorithm. The operations are already looking optimal.

If it really is executed in a big loop, here is what I would do :

- try to precalculate some values outside of the loop
- try to not make such random access to the vector, instead make serial access (maybe it is not possible, if it is a lookup table)
- try to vectorize access (using SIMD or similar functions)
- if nothing else works, implement it in assembly

Comment: What do you mean by "try to vectorize access (using SIMD or similar functions)"? How would I fit SIMD in here?

Comment: @Mads As I said, you need to look at your whole algorithm implementation, and not only that piece of code. If you look at only that function, you will not find big optimization oportunities.

Answer (score 1):

First and common things first:

1. Don't guess, measure! Write some measuring harness around your code and put some figures to my suggestions below.
2. I'm not familiar with the rest of your code, so I might be off by a couple of degrees.
3. be careful about the types of the arguments `size`, `pos` and the internal variables. Are you positive that these need to be signed integers?
4. Compiler types and settings may influence this significantly. Also whether one of the suggestions below really helps or not.

I actually see a couple of things you could try:

1. in the first couple of lines you basically split the `pos` argument into other values `firstc`, `ipos` and `end`. I assume that these values are there in your code previously also as separated values. It could be better to pass them as separate arguments directly. It could pay off not to have this calculation event at the cost of more arguments to the function. You
2. in the next two lines you look up two times a 32-bit value and pack them together to a 64-bit value. It could be better to store the value directly in a `std::vector<std::uint64_t>` from the beginning, that way saving you one "look-up", "or" and a "bit-shift". Are you able to change the vector type?
3. the calculation on this line `std::uint64_t number = num >> (64-end);` looks pretty suspicious. Is there no way to have this value precalculated in any way?
4. the masking operation on the last line `number = number & ((1 << size)-1);` can be simplified. How many different sizes do you have to support? I guess there are only 64. You could put all possible masks into a (pre-calculate) `std::vector<uint64_t> masks;`. This way you could turn this line into something like: `number &= masks[size];` vector look-up is nearly always faster than shift operations.
5. if pre-calculation (step 3) is not possible consider extending the same logic (of step 4) to step 3, making something like this: `std::uint64_t number = num >> shiftvalue[end];` This will save one subtraction.
6. reduce the number of local variables. The compiler will already do a lot of this work for you, but why not help it a bit. Local variables need to be created on the stack at each invocation of your function and disposed off at the end. If re-entrance and multi-threading is not an issue with this function you could turn them into statics or global variables.

Answer (score 1):

I tried optimize your code a little, and do not fetch 2nd array element, if isn't needed. Maybe, it will help with small sizes:

```
std::uint32_t
Data::findInt3(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& input, int size, int pos) {
pos = pos*size;
int firstc = pos >> 5;
int ipos = pos & 31;
int end = ipos+size;

if(end > 32) {
  std::uint64_t t = input[firstc];
  std::uint64_t num = (t << 32) | input[firstc+1];
  return (num >> (64-end)) & ((1L << size)-1);
} else {
  return (input[firstc] >> (32-end)) & ((1 << size)-1);
}
```

}